# How to pass the correct encoding parameter to markdown_py?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, markdown

I use a markdown file to compile a list of web bookmarks which I can archive with git. I'm using [markdown_py](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/cli.html) to convert the markdown document to html because I like the [table of content extension](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/toc.html).

I sometimes use accented characters, my source file is encoded as utf-8, so it shouldn't be a problem, but the output is garbage.
For example if I run

```
echo "é & à" | markdown_py -e utf-8 > output.html
```

I see this in output.html

[image]

Comment: Which OS and shell are you using? What encoding is your shell configured to use? Also, which version of Python-Markdown do you have installed?

Comment: You might want to try using an existing (properly encoded) text file as input? What was the result?

Comment: Have you confirmed the encoding of your output.html file? Are the bytes correct in the file and the browser is just guessing the wrong encoding, or are the bytes wrong in the file?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. the bytes are correct in the file, in my shell, `less output.html` shows me `<p>é &amp; à</p>` whereas if I click on "view source" in firefox, I see `<p>Ã© &amp; Ã </p>`.

Comment: @Waylan I am on Debian GNU/Linux,  `echo $LANG` shows me `en_IE.utf8`. I'm using markdown_py version 2.6.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the browser which encoding the output is using.

Markdown only outputs an HTML fragment, not an entire document. When a browser only receives an HTML fragment, it needs to guess on the missing pieces and appears to have guessed incorrectly. Wrap your output in the appropriate tags, being sure to include a meta tag defining the encoding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{ Markdown output goes here }}
</body>

</html>
```

It is not possible for Python-Markdown  to output anything other than an HTML fragment. A [feature request](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/issues/492) was rejected with the following explanation:

> Markdown produces an (X)HTML fragment. It was never intended to do any more than that. If you want a complete HTML document, then it is your responsibility to wrap it. This has been the behavior of the original Markdown implementation from the beginning, which we mirror with no intention of changing.

More details can be found in the discussion of the feature request. In short, this is the normal expected behavior of most Markdown implementations. To add such a feature would require the tool to be more than a Markdown parser, which it is not. For simple tasks, a quick shell script may serve you just fine. For more complex jobs, a static site generator is a more appropriate tool.

The projects documentation doesn't directly address this. However it does list its [first goal](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/#goals) as:

> Maintain a Python 2 and Python 3 library ... as an implementation of the markdown parser that follows the [syntax rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) and the behavior of the original (markdown.pl) implementation as reasonably as possible.

In fact, the behavior in this respect is exactly the same as the reference implementation (markdown.pl). As Python-Markdown's documentation only covers how to use the library and differences in behavior, there is no discussion of a feature that behaves the same.

---

A simple bash script to give you the basic functionality might be:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                           

echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
</head>
<body>" 

python -m markdown "$@"

echo "
</body>
</html>"
```

The above assumes stdout (it would fail if you passed an output filename to Markdown) and passes all arguments to Markdown. If you named the script `md2html` (and gave is executable permissions: `chmod +x md2html`), then you would run it like this:

```
$ echo "é & à" | md2html -e utf-8 > output.html
$ cat output.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<p>é &amp; à</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going through the python markdown documentation on [output formats](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/reference.html#output_format) again, but didn't find this information: is there a way to output an entire document with meta tag?

Comment: @PaulRougieux I've updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: I figured I can actually place the html tags you suggest directly inside my markdown document. As long as html tags are at the very beginning of the markdown file without space between them, `markdown_py` will leave the html tag unmodified, thus passing the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag in the output file and making my browser happy. The only remaining error to correct now, is to prevent `markdown_py` from inserting `<p>` tags around `</body></html>` at the end of the document.

Comment: That is not recommended and will likely result in invalid HTML.

Comment: I realise It's a hacky way to make my personal bookmark collection browsable as an html file, I don't mind if it's not recommended, as long as it works.

Comment: By way of explanation, Markdown does not wrap block-level tags in `<p>` tags. Markdown does not consider the `<html>` or `<body>` tags as block-level tags, because it is not valid to include them in a Markdown document. Also, Markdown does not process the contents of block-level tags as Markdown text (as per the rules). If you modify the parser to handle `<html>` or `<body>` tags as block-level tags, then the contents within those tags will no longer be processed as Markdown text. In the end, it would just be easier to pass the output of Markdown to a template.

Comment: I've added a simple example bash script to my answer which wraps the output for you.